# how to return only the value of enum rather than kv pair in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, enums, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using **flask-sqlalchemy** api developing and i don't know how to **return only the value of an Enum type data**

I decide to change the db column 'status' from String to Enum but without changing frontend code, so I need to only return the value of enumerated column. I already tried `Message.status.value` but it doesn't work(`AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Message.status has an attribute 'value'`)

Message model:

```py
class Message(SurrogatePK, Model):
    __tablename__ = 'message'
    title = Column(db.String(30))
    url = Column(db.String(180))
    body = Column(db.String(300))
    category = Column(db.String(20))
    status = Column(db.Enum(MessageStatusEnum))
```

Enum class:

```py
@unique
class MessageStatusEnum(Enum):
    WORKING = "working on it, please wait..."
    COMPLETE = "complete sending message"
```

view:

```py
@blueprint.route('', methods=['GET'])
def get_msg_list():
…
    messages = UserMessage.query.join(Message).filter(…).with_entities(

    Message.id, Message.title, … Message.status

    ).paginate(page=page_index, per_page=page_size, error_out=False)

    data = {'pages': messages.pages, 'items': messages.items}
    return request_handler(SUCCESS, data=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question and post here for reference

```py
 msg_items = []
    for i in messages.items:
        element = {j.name: getattr(i, j.name) for j in [Message.status, Message.categ...., Message.body]}
        element['status'] = element['status'].value
        msg_items.append(element)
    data = {'pages': messages.pages, 'items': msg_items}
    return auth_handler(SYS_STATUS.SUCCESS, data=data)
```